# Required field validater in repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater control and textbox in that repeater. I want a required field validator in the textbox ho can i do this

Answer (score 8):

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRep" OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="tx" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="myVal" ControlToValidate="tx" ErrorMessage="Required" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**UPDATE**

Add this to code-behind (also modify the markup a bit to subscribe to an event, see above):

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     RequiredFieldValidator val = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("myVal");
     TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tx");

     val.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is exactly not working? It works fine for  me (just tested). Don't you get an error messages when you try to submit and empty field?

Comment: Don't ask me why, but this only works for me if I use `tb.ID` as opposed to `tb.ClientID`.

Comment: @ngm I think you're right because I'd assume that the validator will try to find the control within the current INamingContainer (which is in this case Repeater). I've updated my post.

Comment: error: Unable to find control id 'tx' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'myVal' .. What can I do solve this?

Comment: I have tested this myself and from what I can tell it looks like the only validation that is running is the client-side validation script registered by the `RequiredFieldValidator`. I do not believe that the server-side validation is actually running. I know that this is an old post, but can you confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Note that I have tested this by both rebinding the repeater and not rebinding the repeater.

Comment: same err as user @user1509

Answer (score 5):

If you want all textboxes in a repeater to be validated by a single button click then thats simple like this

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqf" ControlToValidate="txt" 
        ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup = "TestValidationGroup" runat = "server">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
   <asp:Button ID = "btnSubmit" runat = "server" ValidationGroup = "TestValidationGroup" />
```

No need to check for any event for databound or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can set ControlToValidate value on repeater itemdatabound.

Comment: onitemdatabound get textbox.clientid and than set this your validators control attribute...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSample" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Name field cannot be left blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Can u explain me how u implement this solution on your side.Its working fine on my side(TESTED).If u click on submit button it display error msg alongside textbox control.Can u write your code in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void myRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("myVal")).ValidationGroup = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tx")).UniqueID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    tblData tbldata = e.Item.DataItem as tblData;

    RequiredFieldValidator val = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("rfv");

    if (tbldata.FieldName.ToUpper().Contains("NOT NULL")) {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtDATFieldName");
        val.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
    }
    else {
        val.Enabled = false;   // disable when you dont need a validator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want have a validation per row... Set the validation group to a group per row like this

```
ValidationGroup='<%# "gropname" + Eval("Id") %>'
```

do this in the validator, textbox and the button

HTH
G.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting a duplicate key exception in RegisterExpandoAttribute trying to do this.
I was using a UserControl inside a repeater, when "OnDataBinding" instead of "ItemDataBinding"
This worked for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.DataBinding" /> event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" /> object that contains the event data.</param>
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDataBinding(e);
    foreach (Control ct in this.Controls)
    {
        BaseValidator bv = ct as BaseValidator;
        if (null == bv)
        {
            continue;
        }
        bv.ControlToValidate = this.FindControl(bv.ControlToValidate).ID;
        bv.ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup;
    }
}
```

And yes, I don't think it makes any sense either